# How to combine sec:authorize and th:if in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

How to combine sec:authorize and th:if in thymeleaf?

```
<div class="form-group" sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')" th:if="${myObjct.name!=null}"></div>
```

basically i need to combine sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')" and th:if="${myObjct.name!=null}" and the above code doesn't work as i am expecting how to combine these two conditions in thymeleaf?

Answer (score 12):

Just try:

```
<div class="form-group" th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ADMIN'')')}"></div>
```

src: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this working with the below code.

```
 <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')" var="isAdmin"></sec:authorize>
 <div class="form-group" th:if="${'ADMIN'.equals(isAdmin) and myObjct.name!=null}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code could work here:

```
<div class="form-group" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:if="${myObjct.name!=null} and ${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ADMIN'')')}">
```